# Mailto in ReactNative

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I try to add a button to send an email from the mail provider of the user, like so

```
_OnPressMailto(emails){
  console.log(emails[0].email)
  const address = emails[0].email
  Linking.openURL('mailto:address');
}
```

`Linking.openURL` works perfectly for my other links to fb and twitter. But the mailto returns an error=> Unhandled Promise.

An idea ?

Comment: you should probably use a template string like so, Linking.openURL(\`mailto:${address}\`);

Answer (score 1):

from the react native [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html#openurl)

> **openURL()** 
> returns a Promise object. If the user confirms the open
> dialog or the url automatically opens, the promise is resolved. If the
> user cancels the open dialog or there are no registered applications
> for the url, the promise is rejected.
>
> NOTE: This method will fail if the system doesn't know how to open the specified URL.

you should probably use **canOpenURL** to determine whether or not an installed app can handle a given URL, or at least handle the returned promise rejections.

Answer (score 1):

Use https://github.com/anarchicknight/react-native-communications it is a simple package to open different urls

Comment: I have installed this too. It appears that the simulator cannot make the module work, only on a real device, so I will check later, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are not concatenating `address` properly with `mailto`. Either use + operator or template as follow `` Linking.openURL(`mailto:${address}`) ``.

```
_onMailto(emails) {
  console.log(emails[0].email);
  const address = emails[0].email;
  this.launchURL(`mailto:${address}`);
}


launchURL(url) {
  Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
    if(!supported) {
            console.log('Can\'t handle url: ' + url);
        } else {
            Linking.openURL(url)
            .catch(err => {
        console.warn('openURL error', err);
            });
        }
    }).catch(err => console.warn('An unexpected error happened', err));
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but I still have the error message

Comment: It says Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:0): Error: Unable to open URL: mailto: test@test.com

Comment: ALright, on the simulator, I have the error returned 'Can't Handle url'. How can I make sure it works on a real mobile device ?